# WhatsApp API Automation Usage Inquiry (Regarding Pricing)

Tags: automation, bots, whatsapp, whatsapi

I have been studying the development of an automation product for WhatsApp, specifically for sales campaigns.

I have consulted the WhatsApp Documentation and found that the price per API call for marketing is $0.0625 per conversation (in Brazil).

During a conversation with a friend, he mentioned that he pays approximately $20.00 per month for a service that allows him to send up to 20,000 messages per day to his customers.

I am curious about how these companies are able to achieve such mass message sending at a low cost. Are they bypassing WhatsApp's privacy policy, or do they have some sort of partnership or specialized service in place?

Information about WhatsApp API.

Comment: Both options you mentioned are possible, without asking WhatsApp or the companies in question we can only speculate.

Comment: Many unofficial API solutions provide the opportunity to make bulk bypassing the official solution from Meta. Everything is simple here, pay less, but there is a chance to get blocked.